# user log in while forgot password process begun, let im in?

Tags: authentication, jwt

I'm in the middle of implementing "forgot password". my auth is via jwt access token. (user log in, gets an access token, sends it with the rest api calls).

so let's say the user which currently isn't logged in, click the "forgot password".
i create for him some hashed token, and then send him a mail.
if he will click it I'll decode, display him the change password, and create a new access token, like this is the main idea and all good.

My question is for this scenario:
user clicks forgot password, enter his mail, i send him a mail, but then instead of clicking the url and resetting, he logs in via his password.

1. should i let him log in? creating an access token and all good? while resetting the token from the sent mail (or is it still a valid token to reset the password with?)
2. display some error saying go to your mail and continue forgot password process?

my question is from security aspects, since maybe a user think his password was compromised, and then if i do let him in, then maybe someone who got the password (which isn't the user) can still log in /change password - while the original user goes to the mail and think he processed with the process.

i know it's maybe a rare race condition but i would like to avoid it.

(also, if i do let him in, and then he click the url from the mail which was already sent, should i reset it? in my scenario, maybe it's better not to reset? or if a user click twice "forgot password" should i create 2 different tokens, accepting only the later?)

ii realy would appreciate an advice, how to handle that scenarios, all forgot password related.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an Expert. This is just my opinion:

The "Forgot Password" funktionality should not render the old password unusable as someone else could invoke this process to prevent the owner of the acount from logging in.
It could take you quite some time to realize the email and would cause a lot of headdache.

When someone requests multiple emails in a short while they should all be functional. It happens often that the mail servers take their time and humans are not known for their patience so they click the button twice but use the first link arriving in their inbox.

This is all conserning usabilty.

Now to security:
The emails should also stay active when someone loggs in. As you mentioned a malicious actor could log in and otherwies prevent the owner from changing their password that way.